# linear algebra properties of the trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Prove: If A and B are n x n matrices, then

tr(A + B) = tr(A) + tr(B)

I know that A and B are both n x n matrices. That means that no matter what, were always able to add them. Here, we have to do A + B, we get a new matrix and we do the trace of that matrix and then we compare to doing the trace of A, the trace of B and adding them up. I just don't know how to write that up so that it works for all situations in general and not just for 2 specific matrices

Comment: How do you define trace? The additive property follows from the definition.

Comment: For the matrix $C=A+B$ what is the entry $C_{ii}$?

Comment: the trace of a matrix the sum of the two numbers in the diagonal. So in a 2 x 2 matrix for example, its the first number + the last one

Comment: What are the numbers on the diagonal of $A+B$?

Comment: there aren't any. The proof i have to write has to work with any matrix. It has to be a proof that works with every situation

Comment: I know. I'm not asking for specific numbers. The numbers on the diagonal of $A+B$ are $(A_{11}+A_{22}) + (B_{11}+B_{22})$.

Comment: @user220177 Even if you don't know what the numbers are, you can still *call* them something so you can refer to them in the proof.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, ${\rm trace}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ii}$. So, if $A+B = (c_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$, with $c_{ij} = a_{ij}+b_{ij}$, we have: $${\rm trace}(A+B) = \sum_{i=1}^nc_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}+b_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}+\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ii} = {\rm trace}(A)+{\rm trace}(B).$$

Comment: is there a way you can change those ∑ signs for something else I haven't learned that

Comment: It is a way of writing less. For example: $$\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii} = a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33} + \cdots + a_{nn}.$$

You can see the pattern.

Comment: ah i see ok thanks

Comment: there something i dont understand. Why aii? i representing the rows.

Comment: @user220177 This is the usual notation; $a_{ij}$ denotes the entry of $A$ in the $i$th row and the $j$th column.